# The visual studio code editor does not color the letter "f" format blue in Python

Tags: python, colors, visual-studio-code

This is what happens in my code editor

[image: This is what happens in my code editor]

This code is for someone else

[image: This code is for someone else]

Is there an add-on or something I can do to get this?

Comment: ask the person that you read his code the theme he is using

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch to the Dark+ Theme in the Settings